# Why doesn't Perl's "sort" put these hash keys in numeric order?

Tags: perl, sorting

Consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
foreach (1 .. 10) {
    $hash{$_} = $_;
}
foreach(sort(keys %hash)) {
    print $_ . ":  " . "$hash{$_}" . "\n";
}
```

When I execute the above code, the result is as below:

```
1:  1
10:  10
2:  2
3:  3
4:  4
5:  5
6:  6
7:  7
8:  8
9:  9
```

I expect "10:  10" to be the last one that is printed. Why does Perl give me a surprise in this case?

Comment: A hash with keys 1..10 is called an array.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`sort` always [defaults to string comparison](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

If you want a numeric sort, you have to be explicit.

```
sort {$a <=> $b} (keys %hash)
```

Answer (score -6):

Don't forget that the keys in a Perl hash are always stored as strings so the output does *make sense*.

Comment: Perl stores them both as strings _and_ as numbers. The problem here is that by default sort sorts the strings.

Comment: The keys of a hash are stored as strings, but even if they were stored as numbers `sort` still sorts using string comparison.

Comment: Hash keys aren't SVs, so they don't have the same magic as normal Perl scalars. This is why, for instance, you can untaint strings by using them as a hash key and getting them back out with keys().

Comment: If my current understanding is correct aren't they stored as `const char* key` or at least the C methods for interacting with hashes seem to want this.

Comment: This answer would be way more helpful, if it provided a solution. Otherwise, just delete it, it does not add any useful information and leaves the reader to resort to Quentins answer for a solution and a link to the proper explanation.